# How to use multiple lower layers in overlayfs

Tags: linux, filesystems

According [this](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/overlayfs.txt) document it should be possible to use multiple lower layers with overlayfs, but I can't get it to work on kernel 3.18.13. Am I using it wrong, or do I need a later kernel, and if so which one?

this works:

```
>>>mkdir lower1 lower2 upper workdir merged
>>>echo hello > lower1/myfile
>>>sudo mount -t overlay overlay -olowerdir=lower1,upperdir=upper,workdir=workdir/ merged
>>>cat merged/myfile
hello
```

example very similar to document:

```
>>>sudo mount -t overlay overlay -olowerdir=lower1:lower2 merged
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on overlay,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
>>>dmesg | tail -n1
[42131.327203] overlayfs: missing upperdir or lowerdir or workdir
```

ok, lets add them:

```
>>>sudo mount -t overlay overlay -olowerdir=lower1:lower2,upperdir=upper,workdir=workdir/ merged
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on overlay,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
>>>dmesg | tail -n1
[42155.052961] overlayfs: failed to resolve 'lower1:lower2': -2
```

Answer (score 3):

It may be tempting to use multiple overlayfs mounts to achieve "stacking" of multiple lower directories, however, this has proven not achievable [beyond two mounts](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/apw/overlayfs.git/tree/include/linux/fs.h?h=overlayfs.v12apw1#n491) with later kernel versions. That is, if you mount one set of upper/lower directories to a mountpoint then use the same mountpoint as another overlayfs mount's lower directory, the third mount attempt would fail and you would see this in dmesg: "[overlayfs: maximum fs stacking depth exceeded](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/apw/overlayfs.git/tree/fs/overlayfs/super.c?h=overlayfs.v12apw1#n558)". I see [why a limiting stacking depth is needed](http://googleprojectzero.blogspot.com/2016/06/exploiting-recursion-in-linux-kernel_20.html), but it is unclear to me why this is currently set to 2.

So if you are stuck with 3.18 and can't yet move to 3.19 (as `toto38` suggests) then you are looking for a way to use multiple "lower" directories without recompiling your kernel? If you're using RHEL/Centos/Fedora then funionfs is probably your best bet (`yum install funionfs`). You can specify multiple read-only lower directories in a single mount command:

`funionfs -o dirs=<FIRST_LOWER_RO_DIR_PATH>=RO:<SECOND_LOWER_RO_DIR_PATH>=RO:<UPPER_RW_DIR_PATH>  NONE <MOUNT_POINT_DIR_PATH>`

I've never compared the performance between overlayfs and funionfs, though overlayfs is working in kernel space and funionfs is in userspace (via fuse) so I'd suppose that funionfs is probably has a bit more overhead than overlayfs.

Comment: Not sure what version of RHEL you tested but at present funionfs does not appear to be available in any of the RHEL repos. Overlayfs is available since RHEL 7.3

Comment: I'm not certain what version of RHEL I tested it on, but it was a pretty old. You are correct, and overlayfs is the right driver to use if it's available. The answer scoped for the original question, which was restricted to kernel 3.18.13(-ish).

Answer (score 0):

Multi-Layer Support Coming To OverlayFS In Linux 3.19
http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTg1Nzg

Comment: hi, what does it mean that multilayer support is missing in 3.18 ?

Answer (score -1):

You can use one existing overlay over another one mounting it many times. Just set the lowerdir of one overlay as the mount point of an existing overlay (and so on...). For example, a three level overlay:

- /overlay1 (lower=/ro-layer1, upper=/ro-layer2)
- /overlay2 (lower=/overlay1, upper=/rw-layer3

Now /overlay2 is the ro-layer1 plus changes from ro-layer2 and rw-layer3

Comment: I am not sure I understand your solution, do you mind editing and adding more information ? Thanks