# How to use Overlayfs in Linux 3.19 to mount multiple lowerdir

Tags: linux-kernel, filesystems, embedded-linux

There has been a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044982/how-to-use-multiple-lower-layers-in-overlayfs) with an answer pointing towards Overlay being built into the 3.19 Linux Kernel that will support multiple lower layers. The link an answer provides (and other pages I've stumbled across) doesn't supply any information about how to do this in Linux 3.19 and only states that it is possible.

I am currently running on 3.19 an having a problem trying to get multiple lower layers to overlay.

From what I've read to mount an overlay with multiple `lowerdir`s looks like this

```
    mount -t overlay overlay -o lowerdir=/firstlower:/secondlower,upperdir=/upper/root,workdir=/upper/workdir /merged
```

where the two lower layers are colon-separated. I've not been able to find a reliable enough source to confirm this information though so I'm hoping this post will help.

Using the above code renders an error:

```
      overlayfs: failed to resolve '/firstlower:/secondlower': -2
      mount: mounting overlay on /merged failed: Invalid argument
```

Does anyone know what is going wrong? I know that I can overlay these two lower layers and then overlay the result again but I want to be able to do this on one line due to the requirement of having a `workdir` in the 3.19 Overlay which I want to be absent from either of our lower layers.

Comment: The syntax for multiple lower dirs is indeed right and is what is described in Documentation/filesystems/overlayfs.txt.  FWIW,  I tried your mount command on a more recent kernel (4.1.6-200.fc22.x86_64) on my laptop and it works. Since you've tagged the post with embedded-linux, it could be a problem with the mount utility. Are you using busybox to mount?

Comment: I had a look at some of the documentation on the 3.19 kernel overlayfs and it seemed like the update to overlay to allow multiple lowerdirs is not present in 3.19 despite many sources saying it would be. Not sure when but this must be bundled into a later version.

To answer your question, yes, I am using busybox.

Comment: You're right, I had a look at the linux tree. Mikols' commit a78d9f0d5d5ca9054703376c7c23c901807ddd87 "ovl: support multiple lower layers" is present in v4.0 only and not v3.19. So that explains it.

Comment: If you can post a link to that page as an answer, I can accept it as that's pretty much answered it quite concisely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for specifying multiple lower directories is correct and works, as described in https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/overlayfs.txt. But apparently the [commit](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/fs/overlayfs/super.c?id=a78d9f0d5d5ca9054703376c7c23c901807ddd87) that supports this feature went in only for 4.0 and not 3.19.

```
ravi@tuxpad linux$ git describe --contains  a78d9f0d5d5ca9054703376c7c23c901807ddd87
v4.0-rc1~2^2~17^2~8
```